# Дрончик и его сервисы

Tags: android, java

Создал я сервис в дрончике, который как бы работает в фоне, конечно, у меня там есть ошибки и хотелось бы их перехвачивать, до того, как упадет вся программа, и как-то сообщать об неудачах пользователя.

Вопрос 1 - как это правильно делать?

Вопрос 2 - если у меня мой сервис закончил свои проверки на обновления сервера, как сообщить вьюхам, что бы перерисовались.

P.S. Я тут подумал, может, я промахнулся с сервисом и правильнее юзать `AsyncTask`?
Или даже `IntentService`.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае можно построить такую схему:

- сервис делает в фоне полезную работу
- сервис при поступлении ошибки или другого результата шлет интент с указанным ACTION (ваша константа)
- активити при старте регистрирует broadcast receiver, который "натравлен" на отлов интентов с указанным ACTION-ом (такой как во втором пункте)
- рисивер срабатывает и вы в активити реагируете на сие событие (показываете инфу об ошибке, пытаетесь восстановить нормальный ход событий после какой-то ошибки, апдейтите UI etc.)

Comment: тогда еще пару вопросиков =) вот у меня там таймер есть и иногда таймер срабатывает раньше чем закончится процесс и потому перезапускает его, отсюда вопрос, чем лучше пользоваться IntentService или AsyncTask?